# WPF: Proper place for unregistering custom property change handlers

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a `UserControl` that manually attaches some property change handlers to domain objects. What would be the proper call site for unregistering these handlers after the window containing the `UserControl` has been closed? Using the destructor is obviously stupid because the object is never collected as long as the domain object has a reference via a handler to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`UserControl.Unloaded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, which occurs after the user control has been removed from the visual tree.

Another approach would be implementing the [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pattern. But solution #1 would be the better approach.